# Setting the minimum width and height for the element that storybook uses to render components?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular-storybook

I have a component that "Snaps" into the width and height of the parent container.

By itself it does not have a width and a height.  So if I configure the story like this:

```
export const horizontalSlide: Story = {
  args: {
    config: horizontalOptions
  },
};
```

Nothing shows up because the component does not have a height by itself.

Is there a way to set a minimum width and height on the element that Storybook renders our components in (Without creating a "Page" component)?